# How would aluminum work as medieval armor?

Tags: medieval, materials, armors

I know aluminum was extremely hard to refine until the 20th century, which is one of the reasons why it wasn't used much.  But what are the drawbacks to using it as armor or weapons in this type of setting? Would it be too brittle, or tough to smith into shape?

Comment: Reminds me of my friend bringing up the feasibility of aluminum foil as a defense.

Comment: You sir, need to look at titanium and tungsten instead

Comment: somebody ask this question somewhere else, it is worth to read it http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=230377

Comment: Polished feather light al armor during noon battle to blind your enemy while you charge in full speed to score a kill, the hardest part is getting it in the medieval time.

Comment: How is titanium any better? How is tungstan (heavy and brittle) useful at all?

Comment: I had read a time traveling tip that basically said to bring back a 12 pack of aluminum cans. The aluminum would make you exceedingly rich... then I guess you could build a castle? Does a castle count as medieval armor?

Comment: Aluminum was more than just extremely hard to refine back then. It wasn't possible. Not until the 1800's, at least. Native aluminum (aluminum existing just as a lump of aluminum) does exist in nature, although it is exceptionally rare. Keep this in mind. In medieval times, they'd be more likely to find a lump of gold than a lump of pure aluminum.

Comment: New truck beds are being made from aluminum rather than being iron-based.   From the advertisements (dropping a load of cinder blocks into the truck bed) the aluminum bed does not get torn up as much as the other.

Comment: @Sky: Read *Mistborn* for some amusement along those lines... ;)

Comment: It probably wasn't used as medieval armor, as much as it was a luxury. It was considered more expensive than gold and napoleon had his buttons made out of aluminum

Comment: This is a really nifty question, because it's unearthing just how difficult it is to evaluate different materials for armor.  I'm hoping some SCA person will come by with an actual analysis of how to make armor effective against real weapons!

Comment: Don't forget to watch out for people with mercury. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_amalgam

Comment: Since this isn't [science-based] - perhaps the aluminium is just a component in an alloy or a composite?

Comment: have to ask if aluminum is also medieval or reinforced with steel, glass fiber or carbon fiber. Actually I would consider for fancy reasons, to think about glass fiber and aluminum as matrix and glass fiber as reinforcement of that matrix. Not sure if DIY result will be better then even descent DIY steel, but with force of plot might work. Also just for a reference, not about aluminum glass but  still - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_matrix_composite

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Aluminium has a very notable weakness over steel - it doesn't have a safe load. A steel bed that isn't loaded over capacity will not be damaged at all; an aluminium bed will accumulate damage no matter how light the load (or rather, all the weight advantage disappears; which is why aluminium airplanes have a "maximum age"). There's plenty of reasons we don't build bridges out of aluminium, and this is one of the biggies.

Comment: @Luaan that rather depends on whether you're planning to leave the bridge lying around for long enough to creep http://www.hommeles.com/bridges/vickers-no9-bridge/

Comment: Pure aluminium is trash. But alloy it with a bit of copper and a speck of magnesium, and you get Duralumin. This is a *much* better behaved beast. Stronger, harder, malleable, much less prone to fatigue failure. It needs corrosion protection, but that's easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aluminium is too soft to build strong armor from it.
On the Mohs scale aluminium just has a 2.75 while iron, for example has 4, copper has 3.

The Mohs scale is about how hard it is to scratch a given material and the higher the number the harder is the material.
That means that while copper can scratch aluminium the opposite is not true.

Edit:
While there are multiple properties to look at none of them alone shows what is good for armor and the kind of armor you want to craft.

Let's look at toughness:

> In materials science and metallurgy, toughness is the ability of a material to absorb energy and plastically deform without fracturing

So assume you want to craft rigid armor. If it is as soft as aluminium but has a high toughness any meaningful blow will dent it without fracturing. No fracturing is good but a big dent in the breastplate means you can't breathe freely anymore. That has happened a lot with iron/steel armor in medieval times but it would be much worse with aluminium. Because of that soft but tough materials are just good for flexible armor that doesn't keep the dent, or at least not over a large area.

Back to aluminium. 
Aluminium armor could be good for presentation purposes like for ceremonial guards. The armor looks good, needs little maintenance and is light. If those kinds of armor ever see combat it would be short skirmishes not prolonged battles. So the problem described above would not matter as much as for armies.

There are other kinds of armor that might be enhanced by addition of aluminium like brigandine or jack of plates where metal plates are  added to cloth. In those the malleability isn't as much of a problem and the lesser weight could be beneficial.

Comment: When it comes to armor, you don't just have to look at the hardness but also at the [toughness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toughness). Yes, that's a difference. A material which isn't that hard but is tough can still make a good armor, especially against blunt weapons.

Comment: Yea, I don’t care about scratching it! I care about denting it and smashing through.

Comment: @Philipp agreed. Diamonds are one of the hardest substances we know of, but would make terrible armor. even a fairly weak hammer hit could probably shatter a small diamond, but do nothing to a piece of iron.

Comment: This is wrong. If that were the case, diamond armour would be the best, but it would be extremely brittle.

Comment: This answer shows a complete lack of understanding of the relationship between toughness, hardness, and overall fracture resistance of various materials.

Comment: @enderland The answer is only about hardness, so how can it show anything about the relationship between hardness and other things?

Comment: @Umbranus the Mohs scale has nothing to do with whether or not a material makes a good armor. As Davidmh indicated, it would suggest diamond to be the best armor - diamond would be a _horrible_ armor because it has very little fracture toughness. This is why people often chip diamonds in rings by hitting their hand against things (washers and dryers in particular).

Comment: I never said the hardest things are best. Only that aluminium is way softer than iron and even softer than copper. I was comparing metal to metal, if you think that suggest anything about diamonds that's not my fault.

Comment: Mohs scale is nonsense here. Good armour material is highly elastic, has high tensile strength, shows little tendency for strain hardening, doesn't fail under unidirectional compression.

Comment: Hardness isn't relevant to armor quality.  That's why people have made armor out of leather, kevlar, and other non-hard materials.

Comment: @JDługosz I don't know, I WOULD care about scratching it. What's the point of a fancy armor if it doesn't stay fancy and you have to repair and repaint it constantly? Nobody will respect a worn out armor, and without respect you are dead before the battle, good sir (just think if people care about scratching their car...)

Comment: -1 Tin and copper are also very soft. So we never use them in pure forms, we use **alloys** (eg. bronze) which have different properties than the ingredients. We don't use pure aluminium even today.

Comment: @Agent_L As far as I understand the question was about pure aluminium.

Comment: @Umbranus As I said - there are no uses for pure aluminium, not then, not now. Everything we call "aluminium" are alloys.

Comment: To people commenting here: aluminium is actually **more brittle** than steel. That is, the plasticity region (from yield point to ultimate tensile failure) when material buckles in but doesn't break is large for steel, but small for aluminium. An element made of Al (but made thicker to achieve same strength) would snap, while a steel one would bend. So much for dissipating a blow.

Comment: A friend of mine bought an aluminium chain-mail shirt for reenactment.  It was very shiny, looked very silly and as it wasn't riveted there was a really nice shower of bent links whenever you hit him.

Comment: @Agent_L while it's true that the aluminum products most people encounter daily are alloys, saying there is no use for pure aluminum is not true. If by pure aluminum you mean 100% perfectly pure Al with no impurities, then of course such a thing cannot exist, so nobody could ever use it, but if you mean aluminum which is deliberately made highly pure, there are plenty of uses for it including thin-film deposition coatings, electronics, mirrors, and even structural elements in nuclear reactors.

Comment: @Umbranus, if we're rejecting aluminum alloys, then we also need to avoid iron alloys, aka. steel.

Answer (score 32):

For a weapon aluminum is a poor choice since it can't hold an edge well and, due to the low density, can't concentrate force like iron (in a warhammer, for example). For PARTS of a weapon, it might be serviceable.

As for armor, depends on what you want it for. You can make chain mail from aluminum and it is comparatively light. This may work to resist slashing attacks. However it doesn't have the strength to stop piercing attacks, like the thrust of a dagger or an arrow head. The rings will spread and burst. So you can double or even triple up on the rings (or make them very thick) but then the armor starts to weigh as much as iron or steel. Same with a breastplate. Ok for turning a slash but unable to stop a thrust (either punch through or deform and crush the soft tissue underneath). This can be easily demonstrated with aluminum cookware versus stainless steel. The rigidity and strength of steel versus the same thickness of aluminum is readily apparent. And the aluminum cookware is significantly lighter.

One benefit will be a reduction in rust, as well as lighter weight for the same thickness of metal and the ability to take on a high polish. So aluminum would probably be great for a child's suit of armor or a parade suit, made for flash, not efficacy. Or if you are facing Magneto :)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, when thick enough
The Aluminum castings we use my factory are about about 8mm thick and quite tough. It's unlikely any sword and strong man will be able to do much other than bend it a bit. If these castings weren't so expensive, I'd take it out back and try to smash it for empiricism.  I have broken (snapped) a 4mm aluminum cover by tightening bolts out of sequence, but there where factors such as torque and leverage at play which would not be involved in the physics of a sheer strike.
In a related point, Plate Armor is designed to dent! chest plate fits over padding at a distance from the wearer's body. If the armor absorbs a strike, it has room to bend without hitting the occupant. A semi-soft metal may be a benefit to armor because of the ability to bend instead of break.
Given sufficient thickness, Aluminum Armor is plausible.

Comment: good point actually about dissipating impact energy.

Comment: The problem is, aluminium is quite brittle. It doesn't bend easily, it tends to break (as you observed), and it's not very ductile (so you need to cast instead of forging; and forging is a pretty good way to work with heterogenous material that is both tough and hard). In your example, this can be seen clearly - if you were working with forged iron/steel instead, you would most likely bend the cover instead of snapping it.

Comment: I think the difference between pure aluminium and its various alloys should be mentioned. While aluminium itself is relatively brittle—which is bad thing for armour—some alloys are malleable and can take quite a lot of plastic deformation before breaking. So while pure aluminium wouldn't be a good material for armour, some of the alloys certainly would.

Answer (score 11):

One weakness of aluminum versus iron or steel is its lack of a real [fatigue limit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fatigue%20limit) (aka Endurance Limit.) Fatigue is the accumulation and enlargement of small cracks and imperfections when the material is stressed repeatedly.

To cause fatigue in iron and steel you have exceed a certain threshold of stress. As long as the stress is below that point, t[he metal does not weaken](http://www.asminternational.org/documents/10192/1849770/05224G_Chapter14.pdf), no matter how many times you repeat the stress.

The problem with aluminum is that it is subject to fatigue from much smaller stresses than steel. Even a small stress will cause some fatigue, and over time as the stress repeats, the fatigue increases and eventually the metal breaks.

Take a steel bar and an aluminum bar of equal strength, and repeatedly bend them both back and forth. The aluminum bar will weaken and break much sooner than the steel bar.

In the case of armor, repeated stresses both from impact and from normal stresses of marching, riding a horse, and especially the stress from repairs will cause fatigue, which could cause sudden, surprising failure.

Another problem with aluminum from a medieval perspective is that it's much more difficult to [forge weld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forge_welding) due to its lower melting point, more rapid oxidation, and the inability to use the color of the glow as a gauge of temperature. Aluminum is highly reactive with oxygen, and quickly forms a coating of oxide which will prevent a good weld.

One further small issue with aluminum is its lower mass. A more massive object has more momentum than a lighter one. It's simply harder to push around. Of course, lighter armor has plenty of benefits, easier to put on, less tiring, and so forth, so this is a minor disadvantage at worst.

Comment: > One further small issue with aluminum is its lower mass. A more massive object has more momentum than a lighter one. It's simply harder to push around.

Comment: That would put Al at advantage then.

Also, whereas Al would be hard to forge and weld, it would be way easier to cast. I'm also not sure if marching will actually cause some significant fatigue. And speaking about dents causing fatigue - that can be solved by the same blacksmith who fixes those dents, heat up the piece to let grid imperfections recombine or scatter or exit to surface.

Comment: Depend on what you mean by advantage. If the goal is to make it easier for the wearer to move quickly and easily, then of course yes, it's an advantage, but I did specifically mention that, as have several other answers. The point is that light weight is not always beneficial. Higher mass means lower movement on impact, and higher mass also means more energy is carried during movement, such as in a lance charge. In jousting, for example, where freedom of movement was less important than having lots of momentum, armor became a lot heavier. As I said, a minor point, but still legitimate.

Comment: WRT repairs, of course they can be made, but aluminum is harder to repair using the same techniques used for iron or steel for reasons already stated. And the key issue with aluminum fatigue is that it occurs even with minor stresses, which  does not happen with iron or steel.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your argument. This failure mode of aluminium is a huge problem in aircraft, because the material is _regularly_ exposed to big transient stresses (albeit not so big that they would cross the fatigue limit of steel). And _yet_ aluminium is the dominant material there. OTOH, armour is normally only exposed to pretty small stresses, and only in battle suddenly to blows with impact strength many orders of magnitude stronger. Precisely those blows, where even the fatigue limit of iron is exceeded, are the benchmark for good armour!

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that medieval armor is primarily intended to prevent you from being stabbed while in aircraft design the primary objective is not to fall out of the sky, the failure of aluminum is also a big problem in bicycles, cookware, high tension wires, and pretty much any other place where aluminum is subject to regular, recurring, stresses, EVEN when those stresses are NOT large. See links already provided. I'm pretty sure a medieval armorer and a Boeing engineer are working with somewhat different toolsets.

Comment: Bicycles and high tension wires – those confirm my criticism, because yes, _large_ recurring stresses are precisely what the material is exposed to in these applications. Large as in, not orders of magnitude below the yield strength. While technically aluminium may fatigue even under _tiny_ stresses, that's not relevant because it's so slow that armour would never survive long enough to see the outcome from that. My point is, airplanes, bicycles and wires are applications where steel's fatigue limit gives it most of an advantage over aluminium; armour is not such an application.

Comment: Actually, they confirm my point. These are applications where today, with modern techology, including new alloys impossible to make in the past, aluminum is STILL problematic in these applications, and STILL suffers failure. We spend millions on research to try and find ways to reduce the weaknesses of aluminum for these specific applications. In the case of high tension wires, aluminum is used for its very high electrical conductivity, but because it WOULD suffer rapid failure, it MUST be reinforced with stronger metals. Bicycles and airplanes are both about the lightest possible weight.

Comment: All bicycles used to be made out of steel. Aluminum only became practical when newer alloys made it possible, and even then still fail far more often than steel, and even today, some people choose steel frames specifically because it does not suffer fatigue. You keep reiterating that only large stresses matter, but that's well-known to be untrue. I could provide further additional links supporting this but it doesn't seem like you've actually read any of the ones I already provided, so there's no point in any further discussion,

Answer (score 7):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium#Physical):

> **Aluminium is a relatively soft**, durable, lightweight, ductile, and malleable metal with appearance ranging from silvery to dull gray, depending on the surface roughness.

Emphasis mine. Medieval armor design was based on hardness, stiffness of steel. Weapon needs hard edge, too.

> Aluminium has about one-third the density and stiffness of steel.

So to have the same stiffness, you basically need the same mass, and more thickness - only drawbacks.

Of course, modern aluminium alloys are better than that. At the same time, modern steel varieties are better, too.

Comment: Same mistake the other answer made - whether it's hard/soft is largely irrelevant.

Comment: Hardness is not the only factor to consider, but it's hardly irrelevant. The cuir boulli technique was specifically for the purpose of hardening leather for use in armor.

Comment: @barbecue *Once you get past a certain point*, it's irrelevant. Unhardened leather is somewhat resistant to slashing, but not much good against piercing or blunt force. Even aluminium is harder than hardened leather.

Comment: Hardness means resistance to perforation or penetration. Steel is harder to pierce than aluminum. That's relevant to armor if you're worried about being stabbed. It's not the ONLY factor, but it's relevant.

Comment: @barbecue Historically, steel armour was rarely hardened bfore firearms came around (bullets being extremely soft and rather light, but concentrating a lot of force in a small spot). Even then, the hardening was only done on the surface - you don't want to make the armour brittle, obviously. You can make hard "coating" in many ways, but aluminium isn't a good fit for either - it's not hard, and it's not tough.

Answer (score 7):

Aluminium [is used (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_armour#Aluminium) in modern armour for amoured fighting vehicles such as the [M2 Bradley (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M2_Bradley).  This demonstrates that the idea isn't ridculous.

In the case of the Bradley, the aluminium (presumably an alloy, most references to aluminium actually refer to Al-based alloys) is laminated.  Wikipedia doesn't say what with, but in your case even a thin skin of steel over an aluminium plate could give a hard surface over a tough backing.  This would be like ironclads, in which much of the strength came from wood, hence *clad*. Such an approach would be lighter than steel alone. Aluminium frames, even hollow tubes bent into shape could form a strong structure to hold its shape against impact and support a shell of steel over aluminium.

As Al alloys are quite easy to work, the steel skin might even be chainmail.

Inspired by your corundum answer: You could even replace the steel (if casting the aluminium) by a suitably hard stone embedded in the matrix.  Of course individual chunks would get knocked out and broken, but so do [ceramic trauma plates in modern armour (wikpiedia again)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trauma_plate#Ceramic) and they're widely used.

Comment: Well, modern ceramic trauma plates are used despite their troubles because we have no better alternative. The same thing wasn't the case in medieval armour. If you were rich enough to afford a full set of metal armour, you were likely to survive lots of damage to the armour, and repair it afterwards. You're not going to *throw it away* just because it's dented. Ceramic trauma plates aren't exactly cheap, but they're still much cheaper than the steel armour was in medieval times, and their cost is usually measured against the huge investment of time and money that any modern soldier represents.

Comment: If my idea worked at all (and I'm prepared to accept that it might not) it would be repairable. Worst case by recasting. (@Luaan)

Comment: Yeah, recasting would work. But that would just make it all the more expensive :) Why would you choose a suit of aluminium armour instead of the much cheaper and more practical steel armour?

Comment: @Luaan my preferred approach was steel over aluminium. But that "why would you...?" question of applies more to the question than an individual answer.

Answer (score 6):

### **TL;DR: Aluminum armor is plausible in the form of corundum.**

As many others have mentioned, pure aluminum foil/sheets is a poor (though light) armor choice. However, if someone really wants aluminum armor, we have another option. I understand it's not *exactly* what the question was answering, but let's explore it anyway for the benefit of others.

Crystallized aluminum oxide, better known as corundum, is a surprisingly feasible armor choice. It's extremely strong, the definition of a 9/10 on the Mohs scale. Normal steel has a hardness of 4-4.5 and hardened steel has a hardness of 7.5-8. What this means is that a steel blade, even a tempered one, wouldn't scratch the armor. In fact, the armor would be more likely to scratch it!

However, I understand hardness isn't the only consideration for armor material choice. We also must consider its weight. The specific gravity (A highly specific version of density) for corundum is around 4.<sup>1</sup> The specific gravity of steel varies slightly, but is normally 7.7-7.8. This means that corundum armor would be nearly half as heavy as steel armor, weighing in at only around 26 kg!

We should also consider the availability of the material and manufacturing costs. This is where steel has a clear upper hand. Corundum is found only rarely (It's literally sapphires and rubies) and only in small sizes (rarely over 4-5 grams). This means that you couldn't have an armor made entirely of corundum (except if you allow magic, which I'm doubting based on the question), but you *could* have armor made entirely of small corundum gemstones inset in steel links.

Finally, if we're literally going to have an armor of small, glimmering gemstones, we might as well make it look like this:[image: From the Residenz treasury in Munich]

<sup>1</sup> I tried converting this to density and then multiplying by the volume of a suit of plate armor, but then I realized two things: 1. You can just compare the SGs, and 2: The volume of plate armor is *really* difficult to find.

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that corundum (not “conundrum,” which is a word for a puzzle or mystery) is a specific crystalline form of aluminum oxide. It has to grow as that crystal to have the properties you describe. You could not fashion the armor from pure aluminum and then attempt to oxidize that—you would get aluminum oxide, but not corundum, and it would be even softer than pure aluminum in that form.

Comment: Yes, which is why I suggest that the most feasible solution is to use the already-crystallized conundrum (gemstones), not oxidizing aluminum or gathering random scraps of aluminum oxide.

Comment: tensile strength of sapphire is around 400MPa, as good mono crystals - not something superior. Nice picture - I like it.

Comment: I wonder what the effectiveness would be of a "concrete" made with a mixture of corundum bits, cotton fibers, and a binding compound.  The cotton fibers would tend to ensure that the armor holds together even if parts of it crack, while the corundum would protect the cotton.

Comment: Steel might not *scratch* corundum, but if you bang them together, which bends/cracks first? That's a much more important consideration for armour.

Comment: You can grow salami-sized rods of sapphire without much problem (with current tech). However, plate of that wouldn't really stand against a hit with a hammer (especially warhammer with a diamond tip. Your enemies would have nice swag too). You could probably get away with something composite, like layers of sapphire scales suspended in something soft (maybe aluminium?). Actually, small bits of sapphire are doable at medieval tech, finding right matrix for them would require some research though.

Comment: Corundum will stop slashing blows just fine due to its hardness, but it's got horrible toughness.  A hammer blow, or even a good sword thrust, will shatter it.

Answer (score 6):

**Armor**

To disagree with the other stated ideas here, I think Aluminum could be a surprisingly good armor material.

Disclaimer: I don't have great sources on this and I am definitely not a materials engineer so please correct me if I'm wrong

From what I can tell aluminum is about a third as dense as steel, about a third as stiff as steel, and about half as hard as steel. That may sounds like a bad material, and it is if it is difficult to make in large quantities, but it also has some advantages.

1. Because it is a third as heavy, you should in theory be able to make it about three times thicker than a steel alternative while being about as easy to wear and use. This more than makes up for the lack of hardness, and actually has a significant advantage just by being thicker. That advantage is that when slicing through it, you have to pass through three times as much material, which means three times as much friction and mass to displace, which means that you may actually have better piecing/slashing protection from aluminum armor than from steel armor by weight.
2. Because aluminum is softer than steel, it is more likely to deform rather than totally break. This is particularly good when dealing with blunt impact because it absorbs a portion of the energy of the blow by bending, similar to crumple zones in a car
3. Another advantage of being softer is that it could in theory be easier to shape for the smith, which would also potentially make it easier to repair when damaged. This may be contravened by needing to be thicker, but I don't actually know that much about smithing, so I'll leave that question to someone with expertise.
4. If you need lighter armor at the expense of protection, aluminum would make for great chain mail. It would still do well enough for glancing/slashing blows, though it would do much worse than iron or steel at stopping a piecing weapon. The major concern (and I don't know how this would work in reality, but I would love to see a practical test), would be if the steel slashing weapon (lets say a knife) might just cut through the aluminum rings and get to you anyway.

**Weapons**

Also, just to make this answer complete, I agree with the other answers about using aluminum as a weapon material. That would not work well because being soft makes it not hold an edge, and bending on impact is bad for a weapon for the same reason it is good for a set of armor, it spreads out the force of the impact. Additionally, if you are trying to cut someone else wearing iron or steel armor, your aluminum weapon won't be able to penetrate it at all.

Comment: If you make it three times thicker, you'll have to pass through exactly the same mass of metal as with the three times "heavier" steel. And you're relying too much on things being linear, which is really quite an exceptional relationship, not typical. And while aluminium is softer than steel, it definitely isn't tougher - it will break very easily. Not to mention that steel armour (and weaponry) usually had a hard surface, but soft insides. It cannot be forged easily, and suffers horribly from fatigue. It also cannot be forge welded easily. Aluminium chainmail would tend to break quite a bit.

Comment: As I said, I'm simplifying a lot because I'm not an engineer with the experience to really calculate the relationships accurately. Thanks for the clarification where I was making bad assumptions. However, regarding the mass of metal being the same, that is true, but the friction between the blade and the armor does matter, and increases with thickness, not mass

Comment: It's quite a complicated subject. If this were a simple collision (that is, throwing the sword instead of pushing it true), the two are almost identical. The fact that you keep pushing makes more complicated, but it still shouldn't matter unless the sword has to displace significantly more mass than it masses - which is very unlikely in any kind of viable personal armour.

Comment: @Luaan It isn't as simple as the amount of mass it has to displace though. Think of it this way, when you stab through a sheet of metal, it is still difficult to pull the sword back out even through you don't have to displace any more material because of the friction between the blade and the sides of the hole it left. The same is true going in, and is increased when you increase the thickness of the armor

Comment: Yes, but note that the resistance is much higher when you need to dislodge the stuck blade. Static friction and all that. It's just like when splitting wood - give it a nice whack, and you get through the whole log with barely any effort. Use just a tiny bit less speed than necessary, and you get stuck in the wood, and it's very hard to move the head one way or the other.

Comment: The big advantage of making your armor three times thicker is that it is much, much stiffer (on the order of 25-50 *times* stiffer).  Means it takes a much bigger hammer to leave a dent in you.

Comment: @Mark Is that true even between materials? I don't know how to compare the relative stiffness of aluminum and steel of different thicknesses

Comment: @KevinWells, bending stiffness increases as the cube (or maybe it's the fourth power) of thickness.  For similar classes of material (eg. "structural metals"), that effect quickly dominates over material-to-material variations.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest problem is that it would have been cost a king's ransom to make. As you say it was hard to refine, and as a result of that, incredibly expensive.

> emperor Napoleon III reserved a prized set of aluminum cutlery for special guests at banquets. (Less favored guests used gold knives and forks.)

This is quoted everywhere, unfortunately I can't find an original source, but this was already the 19thC. The earlier you go the less commonly available it is.

Comment: I seem to recall seeing an old British crown that had aluminum as part of it on a visit to the royal jewels display at London Tower, but I could not find any source for it. I did however find Frederik VII's aluminum helmet http://www.kongernessamling.dk/en/rosenborg/object/frederik-viis-helmet/, which is obviously a ceremonial, precious metal helmet.

Comment: And don't forget that the Washington Monument in Washington, DC is capped with an aluminum pyramid. Back when the monument was built, that was one of the most expensive metals.

Comment: @TMN And more importantly, it was a great way to showcase the industrial power of the US, since the expense of aluminium is in the processing, not availability of the raw materials. Too bad it only took a few years after that to perfect a process that made aluminium relatively cheap :)

Answer (score 3):

Chris H already has pointed out that aluminium is used is some modern armour, so this is just about weapons.

If you look at a modern climbing axe, it has an aluminium shaft. If you look at a modern javelin, it (often) has an aluminium shaft. If you look at a modern trenching spade, it has (often) an aluminium shaft. Aluminium is much better than wood for pole arms which won't break, though you probably will want the tip or blade to be something which is harder.

Comment: Aluminum shafts definitely have some advantages over wood, however they do tend to bend when impacted and unlike wood, it won't bend back to its original shape. I know from experience when I tried to make a trebuchet with an aluminum arm which bent in half on the first throw and never recovered. I think you're right that it would be better for javelins and possibly arrows, but for a pole arm that has to withstand impacts it may be less useful

Answer (score -1):

The only true benefit for using aluminum is that it is light, but in the case of body armor, that's not necessarily too good of a thing. Of course, this isn't the main purpose of armor, but heavy armor prevents your opponent from knocking you back too much. Most importantly, though, is that aluminum is used because of how easy it is to mold and bend, the exact opposite of what you want for armor.